# Call Windows Service Client from asp.net page

Tags: windows, vb.net, service

we have an online platform based on asp and vb.net for our customer.

We want to have access to internet connection of client guest, we need to disconnect /reconnect internet connection of visitor pc for one moment.

Our customer accepted to install a windows service in their pc to manage this.

So what i need is server side code of page asp (vb.net) that send a commannd to Client Windows service , in order our page must ask to windows service of client: "please disconnect and reconnect internet"

Pay attention that command must be send from asp .net / vb.net web page code ( running on our server) to windows service ( running on pc visitors)

we have already written a succesfully code in windows service a function that make internet connect/disconnect but i do not know how to call it from web asp page.

Do you think is possible?

some suggestion about techique or code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello i try to make it more simple:

I need to do a web page in asp.net/vb with a button, when web page visitors click on button the connection internet of visitors must turn off and then on.

Visitors of website are our customer so they accept to install windows service on their pc.